# Глагольно-именные сочетания со словом "восприятие"

Tags: лексическая-сочетаемость

Какие глаголы сочетаются со словом "восприятие"? Производить восприятие, осуществлять восприятие, направлять восприятие?

Answer (score 2):

Затруднять восприятие; менять восприятие; определять восприятие; формировать восприятие; восприятие связывать, иметь, базировать.

А также:

ориентировать и настроить на восприятие; пропускать через восприятие; существовать в восприятии; готовить и привыкать к восприятию...

Пользуйтесь словарями в сети, например этим: https://kartaslov.ru